# How to recursively list files in AWS S3 bucket using AWS SDK for Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ls, boto3

I am trying to replicate the AWS CLI `ls` command to recursively list files in an AWS S3 bucket. For example, I would use the following command to recursively list all of the files in the "location2" bucket.

```
aws s3 ls s3://location2 --recursive
```

What is the [AWS SDK for Python](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) (i.e. `boto3`) equivalent of `aws s3 ls s3://location2 --recursive`?

Answer (score 6):

You'd need to use [paginators](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html):

```
import boto3 

client = boto3.client("s3")
bucket = "my-bucket"
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket)
for page in page_iterator:
    for obj in page['Contents']:
        print(f"s3://{bucket}/{obj["Key"]}")
```

Comment: Might be worth amending your comment with `list_objects_v2`:-)
I'm running it on a bucket with over 2m objects and the difference is about 5x faster.

Comment: The last line contains double quotes within double quotes, I'd suggest the following modification to switch to single quotes: `print(f's3://{bucket}/{obj["Key"]}')`

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use the --recursive option while using the AWS SDK as it lists all the objects in the bucket using the [list_objects](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects) method.

```
import boto3 
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.list_objects(Bucket='MyBucket')
```

Comment: You need to do special handling for continuation tokens to recursively list objects from S3 locations. The code you've provided lists 'all the objects' in the bucket, granted there are less than 1,000 (the max result size in a list call from S3 API)

Comment: As of 2021-08-25 the recommended operation is `list_objects_v2` - everything else still applies.

Answer (score 3):

`aws s3 ls s3://logs/access/20230104/14/ --recursive`

To list all files complete path along with error handling

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket="logs", Prefix="access/20230104/14/")

for page in pages:
    try:
        for obj in page['Contents']:
            print(obj['Key'])
    except KeyError:
        print("No files exist")
        exit(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the higher level API and use resources is the way to go.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('location2')
bucket_files = [x.key for x in bucket.objects.all()]
```

Comment: this is a great pythonic solution for the most simple use case where you have < 1000 items to list (which is more common in my case)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [minio-py](https://github.com/minio/minio-py) client library, its open source & compatible with AWS S3.

[list_objects.py](https://github.com/minio/minio-py/blob/master/examples/list_objects.py) example below, you can refer to the [docs](https://docs.minio.io/docs/python-client-quickstart-guide) for additional information.

```
from minio import Minio

client = Minio('s3.amazonaws.com',
               access_key='YOUR-ACCESSKEYID',
               secret_key='YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY')

# List all object paths in bucket that begin with my-prefixname.
objects = client.list_objects('my-bucketname', prefix='my-prefixname',
                              recursive=True)
for obj in objects:
    print(obj.bucket_name, obj.object_name.encode('utf-8'), obj.last_modified,
          obj.etag, obj.size, obj.content_type)
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io)